# Spring Integration nested chains with filters

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a sequence of processing steps that I'm trying to process, but my tests are not always passing, not always failing...

I've produced a simple example which seems to exhibit what I'm seeing in my real tests.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.integration.test.support.AbstractRequestResponseScenarioTests;
import org.springframework.integration.test.support.PayloadValidator;
import org.springframework.integration.test.support.RequestResponseScenario;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@ContextConfiguration
public class FlowTest extends AbstractRequestResponseScenarioTests {

    @Override
    protected List<RequestResponseScenario> defineRequestResponseScenarios() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new RequestResponseScenario("inputChannel", "outputChannel")
                    .setPayload("a")
                    .setResponseValidator(new PayloadValidator<String>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void validateResponse(String response) {
                            assertEquals("AA", response);
                        }
                    }),
                new RequestResponseScenario("inputChannel", "outputChannel")
                    .setPayload("b")
                    .setResponseValidator(new PayloadValidator<String>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void validateResponse(String response) {
                            assertNotEquals("AA", response);
                        }
                    })
                );
    }
}
```

And the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

    <int:channel id="inputChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="outputChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="errorChannel"/>

    <int:chain input-channel="inputChannel" output-channel="outputChannel">
        <int:gateway request-channel="processOne"/>
        <int:gateway request-channel="processTwo"/>
    </int:chain>

    <int:chain input-channel="processOne">
        <int:service-activator expression="payload + payload"/>
        <int:filter expression="payload == 'aa'" discard-channel="errorChannel"/>
    </int:chain>

    <int:chain input-channel="processTwo">
        <int:service-activator expression="payload.toUpperCase()"/>
    </int:chain>

    <int:transformer input-channel="errorChannel" output-channel="outputChannel" expression="payload + payload"/>
</beans>
```

It seems that the message flow is happening and a message always appears on `responseChannel`, and is processed by the PayloadValidator.

However, if a message happens to pass through the error handling detour then the application context doesn't shut down, it just kind of sits there stalled.

Is this sort of pattern, using a filter to pull messages out of the chain and onto an alternate path, supported?

I'm guessing the chain is waiting on a reply message, and some correlation is getting lost en-route.

I am using a rather ancient version of Spring Integration :-(

#### Update

It does seem like this is an effect of using the nested chains. If I move the filter into the top-level chain, things work as expected. Which kind of makes sense, given it'll be the gateway waiting on a response.

I'm using the nested chains because I need the separate processes to individually deal with retry logic.

Perhaps I simply need to forego the syntactic sugar that is chains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, everything is correct.

Only the problem that you really are waiting for the reply in the `<int:gateway/>` and it never happens because you go to the `discard-channel`.

You may consider to use:

```
     <xsd:attribute name="reply-timeout" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                <![CDATA[
                Specifies how long this gateway will wait for the reply message
                before returning. By default it will wait indefinitely. 'null' is returned
                if the gateway times out.
                Value is specified in milliseconds; it can be a simple long value or a SpEL
                expression; array variable '#args' is available.
                Also used for receive-only operations as the receive timeout.
                ]]>
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

on that `<gateway>` or

```
 <xsd:attribute name="throw-exception-on-rejection" default="false">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>
                    Throw an exception if the filter rejects the message (default false).
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:boolean xsd:string" />
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
```

on the `<filter>` and, therefore `error-channel` on the `<gateway>` instead of `discardChannel`.

That is just not a way how to deal with request-reply gateways how you're doing that right now.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I do see where it's going wrong, which I think is really just an artefact of how chains delegate to subchains. Anyway, I remodelled it without the chains and it's not unduly messy. One day I'll get the time to upgrade to a version that has a DSL :-)

Comment: Well, the time is right now though! We are very close to the `5.0 GA`

Comment: I was just going to say that the `reply-timeout` doesn't seem available to me.. We *are* talking 2.2.1 here. One day... one day